# Extract part of Xml document & convert it to Json in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml

I need only to save a part of the following Xml document and then convert it to Json - that, is the nodes with "row" data in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <report>
     <table>
      <row device="Mobile devices with full browsers" cost="3940000" avgPosition="2.0" avgCPC="3940000" ctr="100.00%" clicks="1" impressions="1" convertedClicks="0" searchTerm="purple jeep near elgin for sale" keyword="jeepdealership" campaignState="enabled" adGroupID="7751248218" campaign="Zeigler CDJ_Dealer Campaign" campaignID="134270778"/>
      <row device="Mobile devices with full browsers" cost="3930000" avgPosition="1.0" avgCPC="3930000" ctr="100.00%" clicks="1" impressions="1" convertedClicks="0" searchTerm="jeep wrangler rubicon 2015" keyword="jeepdealership" campaignState="enabled" adGroupID="7751248218" campaign="Zeigler CDJ_Dealer Campaign" campaignID="134270778"/>
      <row device="Mobile devices with full browsers" cost="2010000" avgPosition="3.0" avgCPC="2010000" ctr="100.00%" clicks="1" impressions="1" convertedClicks="0" searchTerm="altitute jeep cherokee" keyword="2015 jeep Cherokee" campaignState="enabled" adGroupID="18188246418" campaign="Zeigler CDJ_Targeted Campaign" campaignID="134270898"/>
      <row device="Mobile devices with full browsers" cost="3990000" avgPosition="1.0" avgCPC="3990000" ctr="100.00%" clicks="1" impressions="1" convertedClicks="0" searchTerm="2012 jeep cherokee" keyword="2015 +Jeep +cherokee" campaignState="enabled" adGroupID="18188246418" campaign="Zeigler CDJ_Targeted Campaign" campaignID="134270898"/>
    </table>
```

Here is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('report.xml');
$node = $doc->documentElement;
$subnodes = $node->getElementsByTagName('row');
$json = json_encode($node->saveXML($subnodes));
```

Here I am trying to extract the nodes of the Xml that has "row", and then convert that to Json.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveXML() in C:\PHP 
\Optima\adwords-examples-and-lib-8.1.0\examples\AdWords\v201601\Reporting
\DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql.php on line 130
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an in
stance of DOMNode

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('report.xml');
$json = json_decode(json_encode($xml->table))->row;
```

This will give you an array of rows where each rows data is stored in a json object.